# Unable to parse the data in json format

Tags: deepsecurity

I have observed that when we try to fetch any information using deep security SDK, unable to parse the data in json format.

For refrence purpose I have tried to get the computer list using below refrence link for api.

https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/20_0/api-reference/tag/Computers#operation/listComputers

I can able to generate output but unable to parse in the json format as below details missing in output.

1. Keys should be enclosed in double quotes.
2. String values should be enclosed in double quotes.
3. Object keys and values should be separated by colons.
4. Elements within arrays should be separated by commas.
5. boolean value should be small letter without qoutes. ex true

Can you help me if it is possible?

Thank You!